# Google Reader Like Lazy-loading of HTML content

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

On a news-feed page I've created I have a list of snippets with information, thumbnails links etc.
I'd like to fetch additional elements and append them to the list once the user scrolls down near the end of the list, so that a person can do this until the end of time. (or the end of 20000 some records ;)

I checked http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload however this seems focused on images, and also it's incompatible these days.

I'd have thought this was done before, but I'm having trouble finding the solution. Maybe I'm not sure what the terms are I'm supposed to be looking for.

What resources can I use to achieve this? I've got the html response ready (returning  10 `<li>` items with content) all I need now is the JS

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking to do is probably easily accomplished using the [Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)

Source is available on [github](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll)